# Can Modelica.Electrical.Spice3 or SPICELib be used in Wolfram SystemModeler?

Tags: system-modeler

I would like to make use of the SPICE models that are available for COTS (Commercial Off-the-Shelf) Op-Amps in Wolfram SystemModeler.

There are some libraries such as SPICELib and Modelica.Electrical.Spice3 for OpenModelica.  Would these OpenModelica libraries work with SystemModeler 12.0?

Answer (score 2):

`Modelica.Electrical.Spice3` is not available in SystemModeler, because of multiple simulation problems.

The `SPICELib` library (if we are talking about https://github.com/modelica-3rdparty/SPICELib ), does not even load, since it is invalid Modelica (missing `within` statements everywhere, `.mo` files with multiple classes).